What is the analytical Fourier transform of an elliptical 2D Gaussian?
I'm trying to calculate the Fourier transform of the following function
$$
f(l,m)= Ae^{-a(l-l_0)^2 - b(l-l_0)(m-m_0) - c(m-m_0)^2}
$$
where
$$
a = \Biggl(\frac{\cos^2{\theta}}{2\theta^2_l}+\frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{2\theta^2_m}\Biggr)
$$
$$
b = \Biggl(\frac{\sin{2\theta}}{2\theta^2_l}-\frac{\sin{2\theta}}{2\theta^2_m}\Biggr)
$$
$$
c = \Biggl(\frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{2\theta^2_l}+\frac{\cos^2{\theta}}{2\theta^2_m}\Biggr)
$$
I have seen the following related posts but none of them solve the a Fourier transform for this kind of Gaussian:

How to calculate the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function?
What is the Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$?

The Fourier transform equation that I'm using is:
$$
F(u,v,w) = \int \frac{f(l,m)}{n}e^{-2\pi i (ul+vm+w(n-1)))} dldm
$$
where
$$
n = \sqrt{1-l^2-m^2}
$$
